# Do I have to encode the username and password into base64 for the Web Server to understand or do I send it in plain text?

Tags: c++, http, authentication

I have been working on a brute forcer, for practice and I'm almost done its just I need to clarify whether or not, I have to send the username and password in plain text or do I just encode it using base64, before I send it to the Web Server.

Here is the message I'm sending right now, to the Web Server.

```
string m;
m = "POST " + URI + " " + "HTTP/1.1" + \n" +
"Authorization: " + "Basic " + user + ":" + pass;
```

Comment: What's the point of sending it in base64? Do you think it would be safer or something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to encode it.

From Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

> The Authorization field is constructed as follows:
>
> Username and password are combined into a string "username:password".
>
> The resulting string is then encoded using the RFC2045-MIME variant of
>   Base64, except not limited to 76 char/line.
>
> The authorization method and a space i.e. "Basic " is then put before the encoded string.
>
> For
>   example, if the user agent uses 'Aladdin' as the username and 'open
>   sesame' as the password then the field is formed as follows:
>
> Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==

More on RFC2045: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Great, I'm going to have so much fun :)